# Main activity with a menu and map fragment (Android app)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-menu

My main activity extends AppCompatActivity where I create and inflate my menu. I also want my main activity to contain a map fragment. This requires that my main activity extends FragmentActivity, but I cannot extend from two super classes. How am I supposed to add a map fragment to my main activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`, so you get all of the functionality in `FragmentActivity` by extending `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `AppCompatActivity` already extends `FragmentActivity`, so there should be no problem.